# Extract string and keep some delimiters but not others in R

Tags: r, regex

I wish to remove the text after the last cluster of various types of delimiter characters, as well as those delimiters, except if it is a closing parenthesis. I trim trailing whitespace first since whitespace is a delimiter.

```
name <- c("Geomdan dong", "Geomdan-dong ", "Geomdan 1(il)-dong", "Geomdan-1(il)dong", "Geomdan-1(il) dong")

#My attempt
sub("[-\\) ][^-\\) ]*$", "", trimws(name))
[1] "Geomdan"       "Geomdan"       "Geomdan 1(il)" "Geomdan-1(il"  "Geomdan-1(il)"

#Desired output
[1] "Geomdan"       "Geomdan"       "Geomdan 1(il)" "Geomdan-1(il)"  "Geomdan-1(il)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to make the first character class optional and remove the `)`

```
[-\\ ]?[^-\\) ]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lBR7Qk/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/xxI8Vw)

```
name <- c("Geomdan dong", "Geomdan-dong ", "Geomdan 1(il)-dong", "Geomdan-1(il)dong", "Geomdan-1(il) dong")
sub("[-\\ ]?[^-\\) ]+$", "", trimws(name))
```

Output

```
[1] "Geomdan"       "Geomdan"       "Geomdan 1(il)" "Geomdan-1(il)"
[5] "Geomdan-1(il)"
```

---

If you want to keep strings that for example contain only word characters, you can either match what is in the character class, or assert a `)` to the left and use `perl=T` to use a perl compatible expression.

```
(?:[ -]|(?<=\)))[^-) ]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L9x5wH/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/KWlOft)

```
sub("(?:[ -]|(?<=\\)))[^-) ]*$", "", trimws(name), perl=T)
```

Comment: Thank you. Why do we need the escape backslashes before space? It appears to work as well without them: `[- ]?[^-\\) ]+$`.

Comment: @syre You are right, you can remove them.